# Order Oracle query by SUM without selecting the SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, odbc

I have a table somewhat like the following one:

```
 lot   |  defect  |  quantity
-------+----------+-----------
 lot1  |  c       |  7
 lot1  |  c       |  2
 lot3  |  e       |  5
 lot3  |  b       |  9
 lot3  |  a       |  5
 lot2  |  d       |  4
 lot4  |  c       |  12
 ...   |  ...     |  ...
```

I want to sum the quantities where the lot and defect are equal between rows and then **order the lot by the sum of its quantity** (lot3=9+5+5=19, lot4=12, lot1=7+2=9, lot2=4), then the quantity (inside each lot), and then the defect.

So it should result in the following:

```
 lot   |  defect  |  SUM(quantity)
-------+----------+----------------
 lot3  |  b       |  9
 lot3  |  a       |  5
 lot3  |  e       |  5
 lot4  |  c       |  12
 lot1  |  c       |  9
 lot2  |  d       |  4
 ...   |  ...     |  ...
```

The closest I can think of is the following query:

```
SELECT lot, defect, SUM(quantity)
FROM table
GROUP BY lot, defect
ORDER BY SUM(quantity), lot, defect
```

Which results in the following:

```
 lot   |  defect  |  SUM(quantity)
-------+----------+----------------
 lot4  |  c       |  12
 lot1  |  c       |  9
 lot3  |  b       |  9
 lot3  |  a       |  5
 lot3  |  e       |  5
 lot2  |  d       |  4
 ...   |  ...     |  ...
```

Comment: Your current query seems to be what you want.  What is wrong with it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to order by the sum of the quantity in the lot but still display the defect.

Comment: But...you are selecting the defect, right?  Can you show us the output you actually want based on this sample data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. Look at the difference of the second and third table to notice what I want and what I know how to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems to be about ordering the results.  The solution is to use window functions in `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT lot, defect, SUM(quantity)
FROM table
GROUP BY lot, defect
ORDER BY SUM(SUM(quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY lot) DESC,
         lot, SUM(quantity) DESC, defect;
```

Comment: Hey, do you happen to know how to use that order with DENSE_RANK()? As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56852428) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56855403) I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: @user7393973 . . . If I understand the comment, then use a subquery to define the `SUM(SUM())` and then use `DENSE_RANK()`.

Comment: That's what I first had but since I didn't wanted to repeat the query for the subquery I was looking for a shorter way of doing it. Now the shortest working [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56867990) that I found was to use a temporary table like the subquery idea to define it. I just wasn't sure if it was possible since why I wanted to know if someone knew of a way to do it inside the `DENSE_RANK()` without defining. Thanks.