# Top n distinct values of one column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions

I'm using a query where a part of it gets the top 3 of a certain column.

It creates a distinct subquery of the column, limited by 3 number of rows, and then filters those rows to the main query to do the top 3.

```
WITH subquery AS (
  SELECT col FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT col
    FROM tbl
  ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 3
)

SELECT col
FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.col = subquery.col
```

So the original table is like this:

```
 col
-----
 a
 a
 a
 b
 b
 b
 c
 d
 d
 e
 f
 f
 f
 f
```

And the query returns the top 3 of the column (not the top 3 rows which would only be `a`):

```
 col
-----
 a
 a
 a
 b
 b
 b
 c
```

I'm trying to learn if there is a more correct way of doing this as the real query is big and duplicating its size with a subquery that looks almost the same just to get the top 3 is hard to work with and understand/modify.

Is there a better way to do the top first 3 distinct values of one column in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `dense_rank` and avoid duplicated code:

```
select col 
  from (select col, dense_rank() over (order by col) rnk from tbl)
  where rnk <= 3
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=01814125c5a36933e1c80e2c0974dd60)</sup>**

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, I'm just having trouble with one of the orders inside the `over (order by ..., ...)`. It looks kind of like this: [`ORDER BY SUM(SUM(quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY lot) DESC`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56850791/7393973) and throws an error (something like `It wasn't possible to add the table '('.` in my language) that doesn't help me much on figuring out how to fix it.

Comment: @user7393973 - what you are describing doesn't seem related to the question you asked in the original post in this thread. It doesn't matter that it's in the same query. If you have a different question, mark this one as "answered" and ask a different question in a new thread. If you feel you need to reference this thread in the new question, you may of course do so.

Comment: @mathguy I did so. If you happen to know the answer please let me know in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56855403).