# Oracle - SELECT DENSE_RANK OVER (ORDER BY, SUM, OVER and PARTITION BY)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a database where I get lots, defects and quantities (from 2 tables).

After changing the names slightly and removing some filters which I made sure weren't important for the question, my current working query looks like the following (with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56850791)):

```
WITH subquery AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT tbl2.lot
    FROM db.tbl1 tbl1, db.tbl2 tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.key = tbl1.key
    GROUP BY tbl2.lot
    ORDER BY Sum(tbl1.qtd) DESC, tbl2.lot
  ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
) SELECT tbl2.lot, tbl1.defect, tbl1.desc, Sum(tbl1.qtd)
FROM db.tbl1 tbl1, db.tbl2 tbl2, subquery
WHERE tbl2.lot = subquery.lot
  AND tbl2.key = tbl1.key
GROUP BY tbl2.lot, tbl1.defect, tbl1.desc
ORDER BY Sum(Sum(tbl1.qtd)) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl2.lot) DESC, Sum(tbl1.qtd) DESC, tbl2.lot, tbl1.defect, tbl1.desc
```

I'm trying to improve the query a little more and I got [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56852428) to optimize it which is what I needed but I'm getting an error when combining both answers.

In my head the solution should be the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Sum(Sum(tbl1.qtd)) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl2.lot) DESC, Sum(tbl1.qtd) DESC, tbl2.lot, tbl1.defect, tbl1.desc) rnk, tbl2.lot, tbl1.defect, tbl1.desc, Sum(tbl1.qtd)
  FROM db.tbl1 tbl1, db.tbl2 tbl2
  WHERE tbl2.key = tbl1.key
  GROUP BY tbl2.lot, tbl1.defect, tbl1.desc
  ORDER BY Sum(Sum(tbl1.qtd)) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl2.lot) DESC, Sum(tbl1.qtd) DESC, tbl2.lot, tbl1.defect, tbl1.desc
)
WHERE rnk <= 10
ORDER BY rnk
```

But I get the error `It was not possible to add the table '('.` (translated).

When I remove the part `Sum(Sum(tbl1.qtd)) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl2.lot) DESC,` inside the `SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ...)` from the query it runs and works except it doesn't order the values the way I need.

I'm not sure if the problem might be having an `OVER` inside another one. I tried to figure out by changing parts and see what would happen but wasn't able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying I still haven't figure out if it's possible to fix the order inside the `DENSE_RANK()`'s `OVER` but I did found out a solution in between the two.

```
SELECT lot, def, qtd
FROM (
  SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY qtd_lot DESC) rnk, lot, def, qtd
  FROM (
    SELECT tbl2.lot lot, tbl1.def def, Sum(tbl1.qtd) qtd, Sum(Sum(tbl1.qtd)) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl2.lot) qtd_lot
    FROM db.tbl1 tbl1, db.tbl2 tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.key = tbl1.key
    GROUP BY tbl2.lot, tbl1.def
  )
)
WHERE rnk <= 10
ORDER BY rnk, qtd DESC, lot, def
```

It's not as good as the solution that I was trying but it is better than my previous working code.
What I did was move the `Sum(Sum(tbl1.qtd)) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl2.lot)` out of the `DENSE_RANK()` and then add it with the name `qtd_lot`.